# Logistic regression model: interpretation of average marginal effect

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, marginal-effect

This is more a beginner question but I am having trouble finding helpful information.

Could someone explain to me

- how to interpret the "average marginal effects" of independent variables from a logistic regression model
- how they are related to the probability of the dependent variable in the logistic model

Would really appreciate any simple/ intuitive explanations!

Comment: I'm certain this question has been answered many times before. Try searching the site to see the other questions that have been asked that are very similar to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered before but I will try to include a very simple explanation which can hopefully get you on the right track.

A logit regression model, linking the probability of a dependent variable $y$ to some vector of independent variables $X$ is written as follows

$$Pr(y=1) = \Lambda(X\beta)$$ where $\Lambda()$ represents a logistic c.d.f.

The marginal effect can be though of as the impact a change in some variable $x_j$ has on the response probability $Pr(y=1)$ and can be written as.

$$\frac{\partial Pr(y=1)}{\partial x_j} = \beta_j \lambda(X\beta) $$ where $\lambda$ is the p.d.f of a logistic function (the first derivative of $\Lambda$ w.r.t its argument)

Notice that for different values of X, you get a different values of $\lambda(XB)$, giving you different marginal effects.

To calculate the *average* marginal effect, you take the average of the logistic p.d.f for all the values of X in your sample and multiply it by your coefficient $\beta_j$.

$$\frac{\partial Pr(y=1)}{\partial x_j} = \beta_j E[\lambda(X\beta)] $$

**Aside Note:** This is different than the marginal effect at the average.